# How to record audio in python for undetermined duration AND allow for pause and resume features?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, audio-recording, python-sounddevice

I'm writing a Python app to record audio as a WAV file until a user presses **pause** or **stop**. After pausing the audio, the user should also be able to **resume** recording. Additionally:

- The app can't know how long the recording will be beforehand
- The app should avoid running out of memory (since the recording could be very long). For example, it could write to the WAV file in real-time to prevent storing the growing recording in memory.

What's a good approach for this problem? Can you please provide some code snippets for your solution?

With **[python-sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.12/api.html#sounddevice.rec)**, I could `stop()` and `start()` the stream to mimic a 'pause' features. And I can specify a numpy array as an output for the recording. But:

- I don't know how big to make the array (since I don't know the recording duration)
- What would I do when the array fills up?

**[python-sounddevice and sound-file](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py)** can support recordings without know the size beforehand. But:

- How would I incorporate 'pause' and 'resume' features? Sound-file has only `read` and `write` methods.
- Is there a better way to stop the stream than using a `KeyBoardInterrupt`?
- Could I create different recording after every 'pause' and [combine the WAV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python) after the user clicks 'stop'?
- I tried using `Threading.Event()` to block the recording thread to mimic a pause feature,  but the recording kept writing to the file

---

My attempt at **`sound-device`** approach

```py
paused = False

def record():
    self.recording = ? # create numpy.ndarray of the correct size 
                       # (not sure the best way to do this without 
                       # knowing the recording duration)
    with sd.InputStream(samplerate=44100, device=mic, channels=1, 
        callback=self.callback):

            while self.paused:
            sd.stop()
        sd.rec(out=recording) # but what happens if 
                              # recording is very long
                              # or numpy array fills up?

def stop_and_save():
    sd.stop()
    scipy.io.wavfile.write("recording.wav", 44100, self.recording)
```

---

The **`sound-device`** and **`sound-file`** approach:

```py
with sf.SoundFile(args.filename, mode='x', samplerate=args.samplerate,
                      channels=args.channels, subtype=args.subtype) as file:
        with sd.InputStream(samplerate=args.samplerate, device=args.device,
                            channels=args.channels, callback=callback):
            print('press Ctrl+C to stop the recording')
            while True:
                file.write(q.get())  # but how do you stop writing when 'paused'?

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nRecording finished: ' + repr(args.filename))
    parser.exit(0)
except Exception as e:
    parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))
```

Comment: Do you really want to resume recording into the same file after pausing? This will lead to audible clicks in the recording. To avoid this, you should use fade-out and fade-in. What are you planning to do with those concatenated recordings?

Comment: I have created a still unfinished, work-in-progress example for a minimalistic GUI with record/stop button: [rec_gui.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/rec-gui/examples/rec_gui.py).

Comment: Good point - I did run into clicking and other audio quality issues when resuming the recording in the same file. Thank you for sharing your `rec_gui.py` code! Looks like that does a nice job handling multi-threading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this solution to the pause/resume feature, which utilizes the `sound-device` and `sound-file` approach, where the current recording is stopped whenever the user clicks **Pause** and a new recording is started upon **Resume**. Then, after the user clicks **Stop**, all the WAV files are combined in order.

([Matthias' code](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/rec-gui/examples/rec_gui.py) also looks like a fine solution that takes more advantage of threads.)

---

To **Start** recording audio:

```py
    def record(self):
        try:
            with sf.SoundFile(self.filepath,
                                       mode='x', samplerate=self.SAMPLE_RATE,
                                       channels=self.CHANNELS, subtype=None) as file:
                with sd.InputStream(samplerate=self.SAMPLE_RATE, device=self.mic_id,
                                           channels=self.CHANNELS, callback=self.callback):
                    logger.info(f"New recording started: {self.sound_file.name}")
                    try:
                        while True:
                            file.write(self.mic_queue.get())

                    except RuntimeError as re:
                        logger.debug(f"{re}. If recording was stopped by the user, then this can be ignored")
```

Callback for `record()`:

```py
    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        """This is called (from a separate thread) for each audio block."""
        if status:
            print(status, file=sys.stderr)
        self.mic_queue.put(indata.copy())
```

To **Pause**:

```py
    def pause_recording(self):
        """Mimics a 'pause' functionality by writing the current sound file changes to disk.
        Upon 'resume' a new recording will be made. Note: close() is not called here, because
        that would kill the recording thread
        """
        self.sound_file.flush()
        logger.info(f"'Paused' (closed) recording: {self.sound_file.name}")
```

To **Resume**:

```py
    def resume_recording(self):
        """
        Mimics 'resuming' by starting a new recording, which will be merged with the others
        when the user selects Stop & Save (or deleted upon Stop & Delete)
        Note: get_full_sound_file_name() outputs a new recording with the same base name as the first, but appends a `_part2` or `_part3` etc. to the suffix to distinguish it from the first and maintain order.
        """
        self.sound_file = self.get_full_sound_file_name()
        self.record()
```

To **Stop** recording:

```py
    def stop_mic_recording(self):
        try:
            self.sound_file.flush()
            self.sound_file.close()
            logger.info(f"Stopped and closed recording: {self.sound_file.name}")

        except RuntimeError as e:
            logger.info(f"Error stopping/saving {self.sound_file.name}. Make sure the file exists and can be modified")
            logger.info(f"RunTimeError: \n{e}")
```

To combine audio (called after `stop_recording()`):

```py
   def combine_recordings_if_needed(self):
        """
        If recording was paused, combines all sections in alphabetical order into a new audio file
        """
        if self.section_count > 1:   # this is incremented when a recording is paused/resumed
            combined_audio = AudioSegment.empty()
            files_combined = []
            for rec in glob.glob(os.path.join(RECORDING_DIR, "*" + self.FILE_EXT)):
                combined_audio = combined_audio + AudioSegment.from_wav(rec) # this is why alphabetical order is important
                files_combined.append(rec)

            combined_file_name = os.path.join(RECORDING_DIR, self.base_filename + "_combined" + self.FILE_EXT)
            combined_audio.export(out_f=combined_file_name, format="wav")
            logger.info(f"Combined the following recordings into {combined_file_name}:"
                        f"\n {files_combined}")
```

Comment: Can you release the full python file so I can embed this feature?

Comment: Sorry @NoName, I no longer have access to the full file. Perhaps someone who extends this solution can provide gist or file